# How to display the specific days without clicking the submit button but when a start date is selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here are the code for the start and end date functions of my two datepickers:

```
   <script>

        var dateToday = new Date(); 
            $(function(){
                $( "#startDate" ).datepicker({
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    maxDate: dateToday,
                });
                $('#endDate').datepicker({maxDate: dateToday});



                $('#startDate').change(function() {
                    var date2 = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate', '+1d');
                    date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+6);
                    $('#endDate').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                });

            });


    </script>
```

Here are the code of how to display the days between start and end date using the submit button: My problem is that how can i display the days without clicking the submit button but when a start date is selected?

```
        <form method="post" action="">
            <div id="rangeDate">
                <input placeholder="Start Date" name="sDate" type="text" class="dateInput" id="startDate">
                <input placeholder="End Date" name="eDate" type="text" class="dateInput" id="endDate">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="submitBtn"><br>
            </div>
        </form>

    <?php

        include("C:/wamp/www/sunstar/DB_Connection.php");

        if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']))
        {
            $date1 = $_POST['sDate'];
            $date2 = $_POST['eDate'];

             if($date1 == ""){
                echo "<script>alert('Enter The Start Date!')</script>";
                    exit();
            }else{

            function returnDates($fromdate, $todate){

                $fromdate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $fromdate);
                $todate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $todate);
                return new \DatePeriod(
                    $fromdate,
                    new \DateInterval('P1D'),
                    $todate->modify('+1 day')
                );
            }

                $datePeriod = returnDates($date1, $date2);

                foreach($datePeriod as $date) {

                    echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
                    echo "<input id='specdates' name='7daysdates' type='text' value='" . $date->format('m/d/Y'), PHP_EOL . "' disabled><br>";
                    echo "</form>";

                }


                    $insert_date = "INSERT INTO tbldtr (DateFrom, DateTo) VALUES ('$date1', '$date2')";

                    if(mysqli_query($dbcon, $insert_date)){
                    echo "<script>alert('You have successfully inserted the date!')</script>";

                    }

             }/*END of Else Condition*/
         }

    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to build your own system? It's messy, vulnerable to injections and God only knows what other problems it will have. But to answer your question: take a look at **ajax** methods.

Comment: @DainisAbols maybe to learn more and improve his skills

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).